# Visual Studio Code selected text color in High Contrast Theme

Tags: visual-studio-code, high-contrast

The text color changes to black when selected in Visual Studio Code.

[image: Selected text is black on blue]

This happens only in **High Contrast Theme**.

Though I can change the color in `settings.json` and `editor.selectionForeground`, what I want is to reserve the original color.

How can I do that?

Comment: this will be fixed here
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/97706